# Watir-webdriver unable to identify button by value?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

As far as I know, using :value as a way to identify a button element should work just fine.  There are even multiple examples such as on the [watirwebdriver.com](http://watirwebdriver.com/web-elements/) site that show this.  However when I attempt it, I get a fairly standard unable to locate message

Here's a portion of the HTML from the page where the button is identified

```
<div class="data-form-holder row-fluid">
    <h4>I am:</h4>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <button type="button" class="btn fb-user-type" name="fbRadios" value="is_agent">An Agent</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn fb-user-type" name="fbRadios" value="is_grower">A Grower</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is what happens when trying to interact with the button (via IRB in this case, to troubleshoot)

```
1.9.3p125 :006 > b.buttons(:class => "fb-user-type").count
 => 2   # yep, I can find the buttons I want, so not a frame issue etc.
1.9.3p125 :008 > b.button(:class => "fb-user-type").value
 => "is_agent"   # I can even get the value of the first one, which is as expected./
1.9.3p125 :009 > b.button(:value => "is_agent").flash
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:value=>"is_agent", :tag_name=>"button"}
    from /Users/cvanderlinden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:490:in `assert_exists'
    from /Users/cvanderlinden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:420:in `style'
    from /Users/cvanderlinden/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:232:in `flash'
    from (irb):9
    from /Users/cvanderlinden/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
#well that was annoying, I used a value I know exists, it just read it to me, but 
# I cannot find the button that way?

1.9.3p125 :004 > b.buttons(:value => "is_agent").count
 => 0   # kinda expected since flash on a single button failed.. 
1.9.3p125 :018 > b.button(:text => "An Agent").flash  #this works
 => #<Watir::Button:0x7d6f5d1340a3b6b8 located=true selector={:text=>"An Agent", :tag_name=>"button"}> 
1.9.3p125 :020 > b.button(:text => "An Agent").value
 => "is_agent"   #also shows me the value I expect
1.9.3p125 :022 > b.button(:text => "An Agent").attribute_value("value")
 => "is_agent"   #same answer via another means
1.9.3p125 :023 > b.button(:value => "is_agent").exists?
 => false        #and yet, finding it by value, supported but failing..
```

Anyone with an idea why I can't identify by value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is some special logic in the building the locator for button elements using value.

In [button_locator.rb, line 41](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/button_locator.rb):

```
def lhs_for(key)
  if @building == :input && key == :text
    "@value"
  elsif @building == :button && key == :value
    "text()"
  else
    super
  end
end
```

It appears that when using `value`, watir-webdriver is converting it to a `text` search. We can verify this by using the `value` attribute and the button's text:

```
b.button(:value => 'An Agent').exists?
#=> true
```

The only alternative I have is to use a css selector.

```
b.element(:css => 'button[value="is_agent"]').exists?
#=> true
```

Comment: is it just me or is that entirely wrong?   Also xpath selection works..  `b.button(:xpath => "//descendant::button[@value='is_agent']")` but you know how little I like using xpath due to readability

Comment: Interestingly, watirspec implicitly states that this behaviour is correct - see Line 17 of the [button_spec](https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/button_spec.rb). My guess is that, in the past, :text and :value were used interchangeable for buttons. We probably should have been just using :text to match what was displayed for the button (ie the value for inputs or the text for buttons). That way :value could have stayed the value attribute. It is worth discussing with the developers. While it might be a breaking change for some people, I think long term it might be worth changing.

Comment: +1 to raise this as issue on watir-webdriver as it definitely needs discussion. I use button(:value) in my tests a lot and it actually matches button's value, so there is something behind this.

Comment: @p0deje It depends on how the button is defined.  If done via an input tag (which does not allow text, so effectively the displayed text of the button (visually to the user) and the 'value' are the same thing, it works great.  If you use the button tag otoh, it allows you to embed text, so the displayed text (and what you would use to select using :text) and the 'value' can be entirely different.  In that case using :value fails, unless the value you supply is for the included text, not the value attribute.  Ugh

Comment: I don't like having to accept this as the answer, but it is for the moment 'correct'.  And thanks to @JustinKo for digging into the source to find this

Answer (score 0):

Try this Line of code:

```
browser.div(:class, "btn-group").button(:value, "is_agent").exist?
```

OR, Your choice flash

```
browser.div(:class, "btn-group").button(:value, "is_agent").flash
```

Comment: Have a close look between what you have here, and what I tried in IRB above..  you would think this would work.  it does not, that is the gist of the entire question